# Some questions about Time Machine

Tags: mac, time-machine, macbook-pro

I have two questions about Time Machine:

1. Do I need an access to Time Capsule (or external hard drive) when I want to restore old version of file ?
2. If I understood correctly if I have turn on Time Machine, but doesn't connect the external hard drive (Time Capsule) to my macbook too long, all the changes in my file system must be logged on my macbook.  Is it right ?  I think they are take a much of disk space. Where they are stored (in which folder) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Some versions of files are stored temporarily locally, when you're away from the TimeCapsule. These are on your MacBook and can therefor be accessed without the TimeCapsule present. As soon as the Mac syncs back with the TimeCapsule, they are longer stored on your local drive, therefor you'll need a connection to the TimeCapsule to restore them.
2. "Mobile Backups" in the Library
   It won't keep so much files forever, as it deletes some after a time. Hourly versions are only kept for a week I believe. From then on it's daily versions.